# App Engine Authentication Error

Tags: django, google-app-engine, authentication, admin

I have an app hosted by google app engine, and I am having trouble with authentication.

When I login using my admin account and try to access the admin page or members pages, I just get a blank screen. I can login, and the members only menu shows when I login, but I just can't see any data from the members pages.

I'm not really sure where I should start checking? My app is registered with my google apps account and I am using the only admin login that is there.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: after doing some more investigation, it seems that my app is not realizing that I am an admin, or that members are members allowed to view the content.

Is there something I can do to force the app to recognize membership status?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running into the Google Apps vs Google Accounts issue. If you have a Google Apps account listed as an administrator on an app that accepts any Google account for authentication, it won't be recognized as an administrator. You need to create a regular Google account (such as a gmail address) and use that as an admin in your app.

Comment: I thought that was the problem at one point and so I registered a new app domain that only allows the specific domain for authentication. The admin address that I am using has also been registered for a Google account and is flagged as admin in the apps console.

Comment: Nick, with what you said I did a little more investigation and registered a new Google Apps account with the same address as my App Engine account. 

Now it works!  

So is this just a bug in that if I now want to make a new app to deploy on a different domain, I would again have to go through and register a new Google App Account and corresponding App Engine account for that new domain.